# Stop duplication data to be input in excel destination using SSIS 2015

Tags: sql-server, ssis

The package attached worked fine and all rows are inserted. what I am trying to do now is if a new data is added into the excel source and I run the package again only the new row is inserted into my excel destination. Thanks for your help

[image]

Comment: `Lookup` is the component you're seeking ! Try it out. In case you fail. tag me.. I will explain.

Comment: Do you have access to temporarily store the data in a SQL table?

Comment: @Tab I only have access to excel document the user send to me

Comment: @Prabhat I try to use lookup but I don't know How to connect the lookup to the destination

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Merge Join component with a Left Outer Join. The left part is your data, and the right part would be your Excel Destination.

If you join on the columns you want to be unique, and capture one of your join columns (from then Excel Destination) in the output, there will be NULLs in that field where no match is found. You could then use a Conditional Split to pass only these rows, i.e. where the join column is NULL, to the Excel Destination.

Comment: Excel is kinda funny about concurrent usage.   If the file is open as a source component for a merge or as a lookup component, I'm not so sure it can be written to as a destination in the same dataflow.   Have you ever gotten something like this working?